# How to remove the error package name and Gradle after clone from git

Tags: android, git, gradle, clone

I try to clone from git this app https://github.com/SimCoderYoutube/TinderClone

and i following package name setting like this
[Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)

but even though i try same way, it shows still error

I followed the package name like that, but it still says the name is not right.
But the package name is the same on my screen.

The gradle error also removed the problematic part, but it instructs it to be replaced with 'implementation'
But I obviously changed 'compile' to 'implementation'

**!-- This is my build.gradle(Module:app) --!**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simcoder.tinder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:x.x.x'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}







apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**!-- This is my error --!**

ERROR: No matching client found for package name 'com.simcoder.tinder'

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

I would be grateful if you could tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a new project inside your firebase account and add the package name there and then download and replace the google-services.json inside "app" folder or whatever the module is called.